# Отбор дочерних элементов формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

и так есть форма с ajax запросом с проверка полей на пустоту, и так когда все заполняем в одном форме полей, и нажмём отправить то, Javascript проверяет все формы, и по этому форма не отправляется. Нужно чтобы он только в одном форме проверил, всех полей. Таких форм 3 на странице. И Javascript проверяет каждый.

```js
$(function() {
  //при нажатии на кнопку с id="send"
  $('#send').click(function() {
    //переменная formValid
    var formValid = true;
    //перебрать все элементы управления input 
    $('input').each(function() {
      //найти предков, которые имеют класс .form-group, для установления success/error
      var formGroup = $(this).parents('.form-group');
      //найти glyphicon, который предназначен для показа иконки успеха или ошибки
      var glyphicon = formGroup.find('.form-control-feedback');
      //для валидации данных используем HTML5 функцию checkValidity
      if (this.checkValidity()) {
        //добавить к formGroup класс .has-success, удалить has-error
        formGroup.addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
        //добавить к glyphicon класс glyphicon-ok, удалить glyphicon-remove
        glyphicon.addClass('glyphicon-ok').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
      } else {
        //добавить к formGroup класс .has-error, удалить .has-success
        formGroup.addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
        //добавить к glyphicon класс glyphicon-remove, удалить glyphicon-ok
        glyphicon.addClass('glyphicon-remove').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
        //отметить форму как невалидную 
        formValid = false;
      }
    });
    //если форма валидна, то
    if (formValid) {
      jQuery.ajax({ // Начала конструкции для работы с Ajax через jQuery
        type: "GET", // Метод, которым получаем данные из формы
        url: "/mail.php", // Обработчик формы. 
        data: jQuery(".form").serialize(), // Этот метод, берет форму с id=form и достает оттуда данные
        success: function(html) { // функция выполняемая при успешном отправлении данных
          $("#myCallback").modal('hide'); //закрываем окно
          $("#myrequery").modal('show'); //закрываем окно
          //setTimeout("('#myrequery').modal('hide')",2000);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#myrequery").modal('hide')
          }, 3000);
          $(".form")[0].reset(); // ресет формы
          $(".has-feedback").removeClass('has-success');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="summa">Сумма</label>
    <input type="text" id="summa" placeholder="4 500 000 сум" class="form-control" name="summa" required="required">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="avans">Аванс (%)</label>
    <input type="text" id="avans" placeholder="30%" class="form-control" name="avans" required="required">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="srok">Срок</label>
    <select name="srok" id="srok" class="form-control" required="required">
      <option value="24month">24 месяца</option>
      <option value="3yearth">3 года</option>
      <option value="4yearth">4 года</option>
      <option value="5yearth">5 года</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="nick-name">Ваше имя</label>
    <input type="text" id="nick-name" placeholder="Ахмадбой" class="form-control" name="nick-name" required="required">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="phone-number">Ваш телефон</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone-number" placeholder="+99897 767-66-65" class="form-control" name="phone-number" required="required">
  </div>
  <button class="btn send" type="button">Отправить</button>
  <p class="confident">Ваши контактные данные в безопаcности
    <br>и не будут переданы <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#youConfiditional">третьим лицам</a>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Не понятно, в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: вы пишите "и так есть форма" и где эта форма? нет её у вас в вопросе

Comment: вот посмотрите.

Comment: а вот сайт http://cargo21vek.ru/jalol/

Answer (score 1):

Задайте для каждого `input` в каждой форме свой класс:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.send').click(function() {
 
var dataform = $(this).attr('data-form');
$('input.' + dataform).each(function() {
  $("span").html($(this).attr("placeholder"));
})
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form form_1">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="summa">Сумма</label>
    <input type="text" id="summa" placeholder="form_1" class="form-control form_1" name="summa" required="required">
  </div>
  <button class="btn send" data-form="form_1" type="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
<form class="form form_2">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="summa">Сумма</label>
    <input type="text" id="summa" placeholder="form_2" class="form-control form_2" name="summa" required="required">
  </div>
  <button class="btn send" data-form="form_2" type="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
<form class="form form_3">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="summa">Сумма</label>
    <input type="text" id="summa" placeholder="form_3" class="form-control form_3" name="summa" required="required">
  </div>
  <button class="btn send" data-form="form_3" type="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<span></span>
```